# автоматическая смена фона setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, setinterval

Есть боковой блок и в нем нужно задать сменяющийся фон

```js
var sliders=document.getElementById('fh5co-aside');
var images = ['images/1.jpg', 'images/2.jpg'];
var url = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  url += 1;
  if (url == 4) {
    url = 0;
  }
  sliders.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[url] + ')';
  sliders.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
}, 1000);
```

```html
<aside id="fh5co-aside" role="sidebar" class="text-center" 
onload="window_onload()" >
<h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="index.html">launcher</a></h1>
</aside>
```

буду так же рад если обясните как сделать плавное изменение фона,спасибо заранее)

Comment: я бы попробовал сделать плавное затемнение, а затем проявление новой картинки из черного

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `<aside>` нет события `onload`. Оно есть у `<body>`.

Таким, образом, если Весь Ваш код обернуть в функцию `window_onload()`. Добавить Вызов этой функции в `body onload`, исправить код с `if (url == 4) {`  на `if (url == images.length) {` и вынести неизменяемую часть `sliders.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";` в css, то получим следующую картину

```js
function window_onload() {
  var sliders = document.getElementById('fh5co-aside');
  var images = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/1/1b/Simpsons.png/250px-Simpsons.png',
    'http://www.vladtime.ru/uploads/posts/2017-10/1508961509_obschaya.png',
    'http://www.vladtime.ru/uploads/posts/2017-10/1508961555_tramp-1.png'
  ];
  var url = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    url += 1;
    if (url == images.length) {
      url = 0;
    }
    sliders.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[url] + ')';
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
#fh5co-aside {
  background-repeat: "no-repeat";
}
```

```html
<body onload="window_onload()">
  <aside id="fh5co-aside" role="sidebar" class="text-center">
    <h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="index.html">launcher</a></h1>
  </aside>
</body>
```

Плавно менять картинки, можно вставив в `<aside>` `<div>` и менять у этого `<div>` `opacity`

```js
function window_onload() {
  var sliders = document.getElementById('fh5co-aside');
  var slidersInner = document.getElementById('fh5co-div');
  slidersInner.style.opacity = 0;
  var images = [
    'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/thumb/1/1b/Simpsons.png/250px-Simpsons.png',
    'http://www.vladtime.ru/uploads/posts/2017-10/1508961423_braziliya-germaniya.png',
    'http://www.vladtime.ru/uploads/posts/2017-10/1508961555_tramp-1.png',
    'http://www.vladtime.ru/uploads/posts/2017-10/1508961522_gitar-hiro.png'
  ];
  var url = 0;
  slidersInner.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[url] + ')';
  setInterval(function() {
    if (slidersInner.style.opacity > 0.99) {
      sliders.style.backgroundImage = slidersInner.style.backgroundImage;
      url++;
      if (url == images.length) {
        url = 0;
      }
      slidersInner.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[url] + ')';
      slidersInner.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    var op = Number.parseFloat(slidersInner.style.opacity);
    slidersInner.style.opacity = op + 0.1;
  }, 200);
}
```

```css
#fh5co-aside,
#fh5co-div {
  background-repeat: "no-repeat";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="window_onload()">
  <aside id="fh5co-aside" role="sidebar" class="text-center">
    <div id="fh5co-div">
    </div>
  </aside>
</body>
```

Comment: круто,спасибо большое)))

Comment: скажите еще если не трудно,знаете ли как наследовать размер и можно ли наследовать его у aside  блока,так как он уже у меня адаптив под все устройства и чтобы сейчас не писать пиксели все,можно ли наследовать у aside  для div блока размер,чтобы он был такой же высоты и ширины )

Comment: @ike77 `aside > div {height: 100%; width: 100%;}`